# When i complie typescript using (tsc greeter.ts) tsc .what is meant by tsc

Tags: typescript

When i complie typescript using

> (tsc greeter.ts) tsc

.what is meant by tsc

Comment: Not sure I understand the question, but tsc refers to **T**ype**S**cript **C**ompiler IIRC.

Answer (score 1):

> tsc greeter.ts

`tsc` stands for TypeScript Compiler. This is a convention by a few microsoft projects e.g. csharp has `csc` (C Sharp Compiler).

You get `tsc` by installing `TypeScript`. `npm install typescript -g`. More : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/getting-started.html